# SQL Server: parsing copyright symbol from xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have xml files with `©` symbols. But SQL can't parse such XMLs, is there a workaround for this?

This query:

```
declare @XmlResponse as xml; 
select @XmlResponse = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Response>©</Response>'
select @XmlResponse as myxml
```

Returns an error:

> *Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 49, illegal xml character*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `©` symbol with the XML entity `&#169;`.

```
declare @XmlResponse as xml; 
select @XmlResponse = REPLACE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Response>©</Response>', '©', '&#169;')
select @XmlResponse as myxml
```

For more XML entities please see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 1):

It works if you get rid of the encoding.  [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp) is an article I found about XML encoding.  I tried using the encoding that it suggested and I got a different error.  However if I remove the encoding completely it works fine.

```
declare @XmlResponse as xml; 
select @XmlResponse = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><Response>©</Response>'
select @XmlResponse as myxml
```

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't know where is my problem and forgot to wrote that I use external xmls and can't change encoding.

Comment: Your link is dead, can you find a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `encoding attribute`. It will work if you remove it or *change* it to `utf-16`. Here are [some details](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_encoding.asp). Following with `utf-16` [works here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8845)

```
declare @xml nvarchar(max) = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?><Response>©</Response>'
select convert(xml, @xml) myxml
```